# Connecting to sybase database without system/user dsn

Tags: c#, sybase, windows-7-x64

I need to fetch data from sybase database. I am doing it by creating a System DSN/User DSN in dev environment. This can't be a solution in production. Is there any other alternate way similar like SQLclient for SQL for which I dont need to do anything except knowing Server/Database/UserName/Password.
 Is there anything similar to sybase(The Data Provider)?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.  Are you looking to set up an ODBC type connection to the database, or an interactive connection to execute SQL queries.

Comment: connection to execute sql queries through c#.net

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: isql

For more information about isql check out the following link:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1570/html/ocspsunx/X33477.htm

I think isql is included in the software developer kit:
http://downloads.sybase.com/swd/summary.do?client=support&baseprod=1038